# How to add Microsoft Connected Service in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In my ASPNet.Core project, I am trying to get access to 'WCF Services' and tried to install 'Visual Studio WCF Connected Service' (Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/25/announcing-wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-rc2-and-asp-net-core-rc2/).  However, it kept saying that I had to have 'Microsoft Connected Services' even though I have already had it installed.

So, I did uninstall 'Microsoft Connected Services' and tried to re-install it back.

But I couldn't find that extension anywhere and have no idea how to install them.  Is there any separate installer to install that one?  Please help me.

Please see the error message while trying to install VS WCF Connected Service.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted.  If you have ever encountered the same problem...

Please uninstall & re-install Visual Studio 2015 again.

Restart several time during installation.

Try to install 'Visual Studio WCF Connected Service' again and it will work now.

Comment: Going to Programs and Features, clicking Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 with Updates, and clicking Change, then Repair worked for me (uninstall was not necessary). The repair notified a few already-installed products could not be installed, but that didn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Just in case anyone is getting the same for `VS2019`, for your information - `Microsoft Connected Services` have been deprecated in `VS2019` according to Angelos Petropoulos (PM for the .NET Web Tools team at Microsoft) - see [VS2019 Preview: cannot install connected service extension updated from VS2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/468751/vs2019-preview-cannot-install-connected-service-ex.html)